# What's wrong with my google actions response that prevents users input from working?

Tags: actions-on-google

So, I am in the process of writing some Google Actions code against the Actions SDK.  I am able to receive the requests and process them fine.  I am also able to send responses that do not expect user response fine.  However, when I send a response that expects a user to make a choice, the google assistant just keeps asking the question over and over no matter what the user says (except stop of course).  Here's my response json.  Can anyone help?

I should note that ActionOneIntent, ActionTwoIntent, and ActionThreeIntent are all configured properly in the action.json file, and work properly when invoked via a deep command to my service (ok google, ask my service to open action two).

I just can't get a response to this packet to work:

```
{
   "conversation_token":"{REMOVED}",
   "expect_user_response":true,
   "expected_inputs":[
   {
     "input_prompt":{
        "initial_prompts":[
           {
              "ssml":"<speak><p>Hello, would you like choice one, two, or three?</p></speak>"
           }
        ]
     },
     "possible_intents":[
        {
           "intent":"AnswerOneIntent"
        },
        {
           "intent":"AnswerTwoIntent"
        },
        {
           "intent":"AnswerThreeIntent"
        }
     ]
  }
```

]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the earliest version of the Actions SDK you could define "inDialogTriggers" as part of your Actions package. However, this was removed some time in December and the idea now is that developers process "assistant.intent.action.TEXT" which is the raw transcription of the user's input.

As such your only "possible intent" in the response should be "assistant.intent.action.TEXT" at this point. See here for reference: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#http-response

Comment: Thank you for that!!  It did resolve the issue of endless looping of the question no matter what I said.  I've marked your answer as accepted.

However, now I get an intent back with the raw text the user spoke.  I guess google expects us to do the natural language processing on any responses to this intent (the only choice I have).  Major bummer.

Comment: The NLP solution that Google provides is through API.AI - the Actions API is mostly for people/organizations who *want* to do the NLP themselves.